# What's the proper way to configure an AWS Elastic Beanstalk application load balancer's default listener using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm configuring my Elastic Beanstalk environments using Terraform, and I can't seem to get the default listener configuration to work for the ALB. All I'm really looking to do is to have the default listener (port 80) forward to a process named "redirect" instead of the process named "default".

The default listener uses "HTTP" protocol, so it should have no SSL configuration, but AWS keeps giving me an error when it tries to apply the configuration to the environment:

`Updating Load Balancer listener ... failed Reason: Resource handler returned message: "SSL policy cannot be empty"`.

I'm creating my EB environments by first creating a configuration template using `aws_elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template`, then associating it in my environment configuration.

I've tried setting the `SSLPolicy` and `SSLCertificateArns` properties to `""`, `null`, and not setting them at all, but either way I get the above error. Terraform always sets those properties to `""` if I don't set them manually. If I try setting those properties to actual values, AWS instead gives me an error that says HTTP listeners can't have an SSL policy.

**Additional Context**

Here is the relevant portion of my configuration. This is from a module I wrote that creates many different environments, so it's dynamic:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template" "env_template" {
  
  ...

  #
  # Dynamic load balancer listeners
  #
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.listeners

    content {
      name      = "DefaultProcess"
      namespace = setting.value["port"] == "80" ? "aws:elbv2:listener:default" : "aws:elbv2:listener:${setting.value["port"]}"
      value     = setting.value["process"]
    }
  }
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.listeners

    content {
      name      = "Protocol"
      namespace = setting.value["port"] == "80" ? "aws:elbv2:listener:default" : "aws:elbv2:listener:${setting.value["port"]}"
      value     = setting.value["protocol"]
    }
  }
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.listeners

    content {
      name      = "ListenerEnabled"
      namespace = setting.value["port"] == "80" ? "aws:elbv2:listener:default" : "aws:elbv2:listener:${setting.value["port"]}"
      value     = setting.value["enabled"]
    }
  }
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = [
      for listener in var.listeners : listener
      if listener.protocol == "HTTPS"
    ]

    content {
      name      = "SSLCertificateArns"
      namespace = setting.value["port"] == "80" ? "aws:elbv2:listener:default" : "aws:elbv2:listener:${setting.value["port"]}"
      value     = setting.value["ssl_cert_arn"]
    }
  }
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = [
      for listener in var.listeners : listener
      if listener.protocol == "HTTPS"
    ]

    content {
      name      = "SSLPolicy"
      namespace = setting.value["port"] == "80" ? "aws:elbv2:listener:default" : "aws:elbv2:listener:${setting.value["port"]}"
      value     = setting.value["ssl_policy"]
    }
  }

...
```

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "env" {
  count = 2

  name        = element(var.environment_names, count.index)
  application = var.application_name

  tier                   = "WebServer"
  wait_for_ready_timeout = "20m"
  template_name          = aws_elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template.env_template.name
}
```

The end result is that the state file contains these (and only these) entries for the default listener:

```
{
  "name": "DefaultProcess",
  "namespace": "aws:elbv2:listener:default",
  "resource": null,
  "value": "redirect"

{
  "name": "ListenerEnabled",
  "namespace": "aws:elbv2:listener:default",
  "resource": null,
  "value": "true"
},
{
  "name": "Protocol",
  "namespace": "aws:elbv2:listener:default",
  "resource": null,
  "value": "HTTP"
}
```

But, when I download the saved configuration from S3, it contains this:

```
aws:elbv2:listener:default:
    ListenerEnabled: true
    SSLPolicy: ''
    SSLCertificateArns: ''
    DefaultProcess: redirect
    Protocol: HTTP
```

For comparison, if I configure an environment manually in the Console and save the configuration, it instead contains this:

```
:default.aws:elbv2:listener:default:
    ListenerEnabled: true
    DefaultProcess: redirect
```

I can't figure out how to get Terraform to create the above configuration for the default listener.

Comment: If you are familiar with TF and IaC in general, you might want to avoid beanstalk as one its main selling point is that you don't have to deal with IaC setup yourself.

Comment: @jordanm Fair point, 90% of the headaches I've had since moving to Terraform have come from trying to get Elastic Beanstalk to do what we need. Long-term, we'll move away from EB, but for now we have quite a few apps running in there and I'm just learning Terraform, so that'll have to be a future change

Comment: Agree with @jordanm Beanstalk generates cloudformation config... and you're using Terraform to create Beanstalk config. With that said, I would look at the cloudformation template Beanstalk generated and see where the SSL issue is & it could give you a clue to where in Beanstalk it's generated. I would also put in an AWS Support Ticket if you have that option & see what they say.